# Decode the geocode parameter from shared Google Maps directions

Tags: google-maps, url, base64, decode

I am running a webapp which takes a user's Google Maps directions link to extract the exact route. I managed to get this done with URL from the Google Maps desktop website. However, when the user shares his route (verified with the Google Maps v. 10.5.1 on Android), I get a text describing it and an URL, for instance:

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Place%20Gutenberg&daddr=Total%20Access%20to%3ASaverne%20to%3A37%20Rue%20Principale&geocode=FXFK5QIdSDp2ACkDNviMUsiWRzEwht7l1Vpwow%3D%3D%3BFZuC5QId9qJ1ACkJCEId2beWRzHWFfoyuzuJzA%3D%3D%3BFQy05wIdoWVwACmdE_u4pKCWRzGiu3h9VRmREQ%3D%3D%3BFaqo5QIdNkd2ACmR2fo9b8iWRzHOHc1chiuP1Q%3D%3D&dirflg=d

I am able to get the starting address, waypoints and destination for the first part of the URL. However, as you can see, the addresses are incomplete and I can't use them in the Maps API to get the route.

**The information I need is in the geocode parameter**. I noticed that it encodes the starting addresses, waypoints and destination finishing by "==" and they are separated by a ";". It is almost a base64 encoded string, with the slight difference that the "+/" characters are replaced by the "-_".

If I try to decode in base64 the first element in the geocode field, I get these bytes (Python 3.7):
b'\x15qJ\xe5\x02\x1dH:v\x00)\x036\xf8\x8cR\xc8\x96G10\x86\xde\xe5\xd5Zp\xa3'

I guess there are the coordinates of the point. Does someone know how to convert these encoded strings to extract the coordinates? If possible in Python but I will translate if you have a solution in another language.

Thanks a lot!